# Dropdown auto fill in form, including checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am busy with a script that can create invoices. I have found a script on StackOverflow where I can fill in the form via dropdown.

```
<?
        $sPrijzen = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prices WHERE company='".$CID."' ")or die(mysql_Error());
    ?>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var omschrijving = new Array();
 var ppe = new Array();
var btw = new Array();
var btw_percentage = new Array();

 omschrijving[0] = "";
ppe[0] = "";
btw[0] = "";
 btw_percentage[0] = "";

<?
$i = 1;
while($fPrijzen = mysql_fetch_assoc($sPrijzen))
{
    ?>
omschrijving[<?=$i;?>] = "<?=$fPrijzen['omschrijving'];?>"
ppe[<?=$i;?>] = "<?=$fPrijzen['ppe'];?>"
btw[<?=$i;?>] = "<?=$fPrijzen['btw'];?>"
btw_percentage[<?=$i;?>] = "<?=$fPrijzen['ppe'];?>"
    <?
    $i++;
}
  ?>


    function Choice1() {
        //x = document.getElementById("users");
        y = document.getElementById("selectProduct1");

          //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
          document.getElementById("omschrijving").value = omschrijving[y.selectedIndex];
          document.getElementById("ppe").value = ppe[y.selectedIndex];
          document.getElementById("btw").value = btw[y.selectedIndex];
          document.getElementById("btw_percentage").value =   btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex];
     }


</script>
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
    <select id="selectProduct1" name="users" onChange='Choice1();'><option></option>
<option value="1">Product 1</option>
<option value="2">Product 2</option>
<option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>
<p>ids <input type="text" id="omschrijving" name="id" ></p>
<p>use <input type="text" id="ppe" name="username" ></p>
<p>ful <input type="text" id="btw" name="full_name" ></p>
<input type="checkbox" name="1-zesprocent" value="ja" <? if?> /> 6&#37;
<input type="checkbox" name="1-nulprocent" value="ja" /> 0&#37;
```

Everything works. The values of the text inputs will be autofilled. But now I have 2 checkboxes with the VAT's of our country (6% and 0%). And I want to have it automatically 'checked' when it is selected via dropdown.  Can someone help me out with this thing?

Comment: When do you want these two checkboxes to be checked? Dropdown has values Product 1, 2 and 3 ..

Comment: The id btw_percentage contains a value like '6', '0p' or '21' (the standard VAT). When the value is 6 the checkbox name="1-zesprocent" need to be checked and when the value is 0p the checkbox name="1-nulprocent" needs to be checked. If the value is other then 0p or 6 no checkbox need to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, give both checkboxes the same name so they are grouped and give proper value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="btw_percentage" value="6" /> 6%
<input type="checkbox" name="btw_percentage" value="0" /> 0%
```

Now you need to add some logic to the function and tick the proper checkbox based on the value from the PHP code:

```
function Choice1() {
    //...
    var percentage = btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex];
    alert("DEBUG --- value from PHP: " + percentage);
    var oCheckboxGroup = document.getElementsByName("btw_percentage");
    for (var i = 0; i <oCheckboxGroup.length; i++) {
        var curCheckbox = oCheckboxGroup[i];
        alert("DEBUG --- value of checkbox #" + (i + 1) + " is: " + curCheckbox.value);
        curCheckbox.checked = (curCheckbox.value === percentage);
    }
 }
```

The values in the PHP array `$fPrijzen['ppe'];` should be either "6" or "0" and it should work.

Note: added some debug lines to help debug problems with the code, when all is working properly remove or put them in remark.

Comment: Thank you! We're almost there.. but when I use this code and the value of ppe = 0, he select both of the checkboxes. And when ppe is another value (like 21) he select also the 6% checkbox

Comment: @user2721621 so you did something wrong, probably put `value="0"` on both.

Comment: I now have this:     <input type="checkbox" name="btw_percentage" id="btw_percentage" value="6" /> 6&#37;
                   <input type="checkbox" name="btw_percentage" id="btw_percentage" value="0" /> 0&#37;

It worked, but he select the 6% no matter what the value of ppe is.

Comment: Give them different ID, you must not have same ID to more than one element. Have only the name equal for both.

Comment: I give them different ID now, but when I change ppe to something like '15' or any other number it keeps selecting the 6% checkbox.     <input type="checkbox" name="btw_percentage" id="btw_percentage" value="6" /> 6%                   <input type="checkbox" name="btw_percentage" id="btw_percentage1" value="0" /> 0%

Comment: @user2721621 need to debug. See my edited code, apply it and let me know what messages you see.

Comment: DEBUG --- value from PHP: 6  
DEBUG --- value of checkbox #1 is: 6
DEBUG --- value of checkbox #2 is: 0
Those three messages did I get

And when i look in my sourcecode to see the output of the while() loop:
 omschrijving[1] = "Coffee"
 ppe[1] = "6"
 btw[1] = "9"
 btw_percentage[1] = "6"
   omschrijving[2] = "Tea"
 ppe[2] = "21"
 btw[2] = "32"
 btw_percentage[2] = "0"

Comment: @user2721621 sorry, no idea... one thing you can try is change the line to `curCheckbox.checked = (curCheckbox.value == percentage);` (two equal signs instead of three) but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I fixed the whole problem. I used your script. The problem was that i had still this line in my script: document.getElementById("btw_percentage").value = btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex];  Now i deleted that row, and it all works. Thank you!

Comment: Lol! Knew it's something totally unrelated to what I wrote. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I had not refreshed the page before posting, the question is solved with a better solution by Shadow Wizard.

I have tried this solution, I think it could solve your problem. Adding some code to your function Choice1()

```
function Choice1() {
    //x = document.getElementById("users");
    y = document.getElementById("selectProduct1");

      //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
      document.getElementById("omschrijving").value = omschrijving[y.selectedIndex];
      document.getElementById("ppe").value = ppe[y.selectedIndex];
      document.getElementById("btw").value = btw[y.selectedIndex];
      document.getElementById("btw_percentage").value = btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex];

      var checkbox_a = document.getElementById("1-zesprocent");
      var checkbox_b = document.getElementById("1-nulprocent");
      checkbox_a.checked = 0;
      checkbox_b.checked = 0;
      if (btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex] == '6')
      {
       var check_box = document.getElementById("1-zesprocent");
       checkbox_a.checked = 1;
      }
      else if (btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex] == '0p')
      {
       var check_box = document.getElementById("1-nulprocent");
       checkbox_b.checked = 1;
      }

     };
```

I have added an ID attribute to each checkbox, to select them with javascript.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1-zesprocent" name="1-zesprocent" value="ja" />
<input type="checkbox" id="1-nulprocent" name="1-nulprocent" value="ja" />
```

When the function Choice1() is launched it uncheck both checkboxes, and check one of them if the value in `btw_percentage[y.selectedIndex]` is '6' or '0p'.